# 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'save' - Django

Tags: python, django

In Django, I'm using `@receiver` to save a model object named `CampaignProfile` like so:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=UserModel)
def save_campaign(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.CampaignProfile.save()
```

I've created a custom user model named `UserModel` which needs to be linked with the `CampaignProfile` model, where the CampaignProfile looks something like this...

```
class CampaignProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, related_name='CampaignProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    campaign_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Title')
```

However when I try to create a new super user through the Terminal then I get an error like so...

> AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'save'

Does anybody know why creating a new super user would bring up this sort of error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

That's correct - you can't call `save()` directly on your model - you can only call `save()` on object instances. Looks like you need to create some default user profile once the user is created. Try this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=UserModel)
def save_campaign(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        CampaignProfile.objects.create(
           user = instance,
           title = "Profile default title"
        )
```